# How do I draw this plot in Maple?

Tags: plot, draw, maple

Please guide me for the code to draw the following graphs in Maple program?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzc0G.jpg)
ِDraw this plot in Maple???
Colors if possible
Draw this diagram in Maple
X axis [-1,1]
Y axis [0.000001 , 0.0001]
thank you...